# AlertBox VBSCRIPT IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript, internet-explorer-11

I have .js and .vbs.

.js

```
IE4 = document.all;

function newAlert(title,mess,icon) {
   (IE4) ? makeMsgBox(title,mess,icon,0,0,0) : alert(mess);
}

function msgBox(title,mess,icon,buts,defbut) {
   retVal = (IE4) ? makeMsgBox(title,mess,icon,buts,defbut,0) : null;
   return retVal;
}
```

.vbs

```
Function makeMsgBox(tit,mess,icons,buts,defs,mods)
   butVal = buts + (icons*16) + (defs*256) + (mods*4096)
   makeMsgBox = MsgBox(mess,butVal,tit)
End Function

Function makeInputBox(tit,pr,def)
   makeInputBox = InputBox(pr,tit,def)
End Function
```

I need alternative way for this in IE11. I know that IE11 is not supporting .vbs and document.all anymore. But I need same functionality. Any options?

Answer (score 0):

What "functionality" do you need exactly?

In IE11, in the Internet Zone, your best option is either `alert()` from JavaScript, or you could create a HTML popup that *looks like* the old VBScript alert box.